# Getting error "Request timed out" using telegram bot with c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I am go send 10 images with caption on the telegram bot using c#.but just go there 2 or 3 image and getting error like this "**Request timed out**" from the api "**SendPhotoAsync**".i don't know where is mistake. i am run this in my local pc. and my pc is fully under in network so why i am getting this error any one know please let me.

This is my code=>

```
public async Task SendCasesOnTelegramBot()
{             
  DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Setting.ConnectionString(), "GetPostForTelegramBot");
if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       var imageData = webClient.DownloadData(MediaPath + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Url"].ToString());
       ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);       
       var sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString());                                 

           await Bot.SendPhotoAsync("@abcgrop", new FileToSend(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Url"].ToString(), ms), sb.ToString()); // here i am getting error

  }
 }
}
```

this is my code and i am getting error.

Comment: Maybe your Internet connection is weak. Try adding a short wait time between each send.

Comment: @AliHashemi can you please tell me where is set short wit time between each send plz i am facing issue same still

Answer (score 0):

Hi Set The API **Timeout** Propriety to Higher value like 5 mins.
you maybe having some network issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer